# Need to display a warning message if a product from a certain category is in the cart

Tags: product, checkout, cart, if

I need to add a warning message to my shipping methods page in the cart if a product from a certain category has been ordered.

for example if our customer order furniture from the category ID 76 then i need a message to appear saying "Warning! delivery may take longer than the standard 2-5 working days" is this possible. I know i would need an IF statement i just dont know what to write in it or where to put it.

////////////ADDED/////////////

Exception.log

```
2013-08-27T14:11:26+00:00 ERR (3): 
exception 'Mage_Core_Exception' with message 'Invalid block type: Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List_Related2' in /home/senorehe/public_html/app/Mage.php:594
Stack trace:
#0 /home/senorehe/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(495): Mage::throwException('Invalid block t...')
#1 /home/senorehe/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(437): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->_getBlockInstance('catalog/product...', Array)
#2 /home/senorehe/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(472): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->createBlock('catalog/product...', 'content.product...')
#3 /home/senorehe/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(239): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->addBlock('catalog/product...', 'content.product...')
#4 /home/senorehe/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(205): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->_generateBlock(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element), Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))
#5 /home/senorehe/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(210): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))
#6 /home/senorehe/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(344): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks()
#7 /home/senorehe/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Helper/Product/View.php(73): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->generateLayoutBlocks()
#8 /home/senorehe/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Helper/Product/View.php(144): Mage_Catalog_Helper_Product_View->initProductLayout(Object(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product), Object(Mage_Catalog_ProductController))
#9 /home/senorehe/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/controllers/ProductController.php(132): Mage_Catalog_Helper_Product_View->prepareAndRender(11342, Object(Mage_Catalog_ProductController), Object(Varien_Object))
#10 /home/senorehe/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(419): Mage_Catalog_ProductController->viewAction()
#11 /home/senorehe/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('view')
#12 /home/senorehe/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(176): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#13 /home/senorehe/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#14 /home/senorehe/public_html/app/Mage.php(683): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#15 /home/senorehe/public_html/index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
#16 {main}
```

System.log

```
2014-08-26T14:10:25+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: simplexml_load_string() [<a href='function.simplexml-load-string'>function.simplexml-load-string</a>]: Entity: line 9: parser error : Premature end of data in tag config line 2  in /home/senorehe/public_html/lib/Varien/Simplexml/Config.php on line 510
2014-08-26T14:10:25+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: simplexml_load_string() [<a href='function.simplexml-load-string'>function.simplexml-load-string</a>]:  /config&gt;  in /home/senorehe/public_html/lib/Varien/Simplexml/Config.php on line 510
2014-08-26T14:10:25+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: simplexml_load_string() [<a href='function.simplexml-load-string'>function.simplexml-load-string</a>]:          ^  in /home/senorehe/public_html/lib/Varien/Simplexml/Config.php on line 510
```

Thank you if you can help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adam ,you can do using event observer on  event `checkout_cart_product_add_after`

```
step1:call an observer on checkout_cart_product_add_after and 
step2:in this observer  you can get product id and get Categories from product
step3: set message using session message
```

Code look like this:
**Step1**

```
<checkout_cart_product_add_after>
  <observers>
    <teknoid_catch_standard_add_to_cart>
      <type>singleton</type>
      <class>yourmodule_yourmodel/observer</class>
      <method>catchAddToCart</method>
    </teknoid_catch_standard_add_to_cart>
  </observers>
</checkout_cart_product_add_after>
```

**step2: and Step3:**

```
    public function catchAddToCart($observer) {
            //getting product ID from event data
            $productId = $observer->getProduct()->getId();
            $categoires=null
            $Product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productId);
        $categoires= explode(',',$Product->getCategoriesId());
        if(in_array('yourcatid',$categoires)):
    // add message 
 Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->addError($this->__('Product is cart from Category page.'));

        endif;

            }
        }
```

Hey According to your request:

**Edit:**
create

**config.xml at app/code/local/Stackexchange/Magento33614/etc/**

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Stackexchange_Magento33614>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </Stackexchange_Magento33614>   
    </modules>  
    <global>
        <models>
            <magento33614>
                <class>Stackexchange_Magento33614_Model</class>
            </magento33614> 
        </models>
        <events>
            <checkout_cart_product_add_after>
              <observers>
                <teknoid_catch_standard_add_to_cart>
                  <type>singleton</type>
                  <class>magento33614/observer</class>
                  <method>catchAddToCart</method>
                </teknoid_catch_standard_add_to_cart>
              </observers>
            </checkout_cart_product_add_after>
        </events>   
    </global>
</config>
```

Observer.php at **app/code/local/Stackexchange/Magento33614/Model**
and code is

```
<?php
class Stackexchange_Magento33614_Model_Observer{

    public function catchAddToCart($observer){
         $productId = $observer->getProduct()->getId();
         $categoires=null;
         $Product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productId);
         $value='';
         $categoryIds = $Product->getCategoryIds();

         //static code for match cat
        $matchCatId=10;
        if(Mage::registry('current_category') && Mage::registry('current_category')->getId()== $matchCatId){
              $_category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($matchCatId);
              $message = Mage::helper('checkout')->__('Your product has been cart from . %s .delivery may take longer than the standard 2-5 working days', $_category->getName());
            Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->addError( $message);

        }elseif (in_array($matchCatId,$categoryIds)){
                $_category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($matchCatId);
              $message = Mage::helper('checkout')->__('Your product has been cart from . %s .delivery may take longer than the standard 2-5 working days', $_category->getName());
            Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->addError( $message);

        }else{
        Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->addError( "not match");
        }



         return;
    }

}
```

Step3:**create Stackexchange_Magento33614.xml at app/etc/modules/**

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Stackexchange_Magento33614>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
            <active>true</active>
        </Stackexchange_Magento33614>   
    </modules>  
</config>
```

Comment: Thank you i will give this a go in a mintue. Do i just add this to my shipping methods template file? sotty never used event observers before and still learning magento

Comment: ok, i will give total cde

Comment: When i add the Observer my Add to cart button stops working

Comment: can give me system.log and exception.log.. i will check what is the issue

Comment: i have added it to my question.

Comment: there are some space issue in xml file,so it it create isse

Comment: Download extension from https://www.dropbox.com/s/tf4offkf7ir5hbq/Magento33614.zip

Comment: it works now but is displays the message in the cart and not the shipping method page, is there any way to change that ?

Comment: Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session') change  Mage::getSingleton('core/session') or  Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')

Comment: would i need to change $message = Mage::helper('checkout') as well as neither of them worked

Comment: change  Mage::helper('checkout')  to Mage::helper('core')

Comment: no nothing is displaying now. Does it matter i am using a custom theme?

Comment: it not possible  show in shipping method page...if you want to show then you need to fetch list of product from  and using product fetch its category and match with your desire catgegory

Comment: ok i will give that a try. Thank you for all your help and i will accept your answer because you did get it to work and have been a real help today. So thank you again!